# Show default document extension in URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've been given several requests to rewrite a URL in IIS. One of them includes having the .html page as part of the URL, but without the HTML tag. For example, [www.foo.com/bar.html](http://www.foo.com/bar.html) would be displayed as [www.foo.com/bar](http://www.foo.com/bar) instead. I have this rule to accomplish that and it seems to work ok.

```
               <rule name="Hide .html ext" enabled="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
            </rule>
```

The problem I'm having is that since index.html is a default document in IIS, so [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com) never shows index.html for my html rewrite rule to handle it (at least that is my assumption as to what is happening). This is the same if the page is something like [www.foo.com/bar/index.html](http://www.foo.com/bar/index.html). They would want [www.foo.com/bar](http://www.foo.com/bar) to redirect to [www.foo.com/bar/index](http://www.foo.com/bar/index) in the URL.

Essentially is it possible to somehow force the default document to show? I've been attempting all sorts of strange scenarios using {PATH_INFO}, {URL}, and {PATH_TRANSLATED} to somehow attempt to catch any index.html page to rewrite it "correctly" in the URL.

Example attempt that I know is in the wrong direction:

```
               <rule name="Include /index" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(.+?(?=(index.html|\/index.html|\/index.html\/)$)|^(index.html))" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+?(?=(index|\/index|\/index\/)$)|^((index)|(\/index\/)))" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/index" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

I feel like I'm overthinking this and there's possibly a simpler solution that uses IIS URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

If the default document function is enabled, the index cannot be displayed in the URL, including index.html.

If you want to display the index in the url unless manually enter it in the browser. There are some problems with URL rewriting. Even if the URI is empty, the request is sent to IIS, and what is received in IIS is the URL with farvicon.ico attached. In URL rewriting, it is not very accurate to determine whether the URI is empty.

Comment: Seems like the solution is disabling default document then. When I did that and include a rule rewrite like ^\s*$ to append /index, it seems to work, at least in testing so far.

Comment: Yes. Only use URL rewriting after disabling the default document, otherwise the URL will always have farvicon.ico at the end.